# Ending a round of Farkle in Java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, do-while, break

I'm working on a Farkle assignment in Java, and I need the round to end and points to be lost for that turn if no 1s or 5s are rolled on the dice. The code I have will end the round if the first roll of the dice doesn't have any 1s or 5s, but the game will keep letting me roll until I get nothing but 1s and 5s if that makes sense. The prompt for this portion reads:

"The inner do-while loop
controlls each round of the game, ending when the user chose to secure their earned points
or when no further points were rolled."

Here's what I've got this far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class Farkle 
{
    static int[] rolls = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0};
    static int round=0, totalScore=0, count1s5s =0;

    public static void reset()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            rolls[i]=0;
    }       
    public static int returnPoints()
    {
            int sum=0;
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                if(rolls[i] == 1)
                    sum=sum+100;
                if(rolls[i]==5)
                    sum=sum+50;
            }
            return sum;
    }
    public static void countFace()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            if(rolls[i] == 1 || rolls[i]==5)
                count1s5s++;
        }
    }
    public static void rollDice()
    {
        SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
        
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            if(rolls[i]!=1 && rolls[i]!=5)
            {
                int randValue = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
                rolls[i] = randValue;
            }
                
        }
    }
    public static void display()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(rolls[i]+"  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        
        while(totalScore<1000)
        {
            char ch;
            round++;
            System.out.println("Beginning round "+round);
            do
            {
                count1s5s = 0;
                System.out.printf("Your roll: ");
                rollDice();
                display();
                countFace();
                System.out.printf("Keep rolling? (y/n) ");
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                ch = in.next().charAt(0);
                if(count1s5s == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("No new points scored; the round ends in a loss");
                    break;
                }   
            }
            
            while(ch!='n');
            totalScore = totalScore+returnPoints();
            System.out.println("Round "+round+" complete. Your current score is "+totalScore);
            reset();
        }
        
    }
}
```

I've tried placing my if statement in my main class in different places within the do-while, but that hasn't done what I was hoping it would and rearranging the do-while hasn't done it either. I'm stuck and any help would be appreciated. Please let me now if there's any further clarification needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not differentiating between what you rolled previously vs. what you rolled this round. countFace() can't tell whether a 1 or 5 was rolled this round or last round. Split this into two different arrays / Collections to solve the problem.

Right now, you're asking the user whether to keep rolling even if no 1's or 5's are rolled; is that what you want?

Also, create a SecureRandom just once, not every time through the loop.

Comment: Awesome thank you for that information. And no, what I want to happen is if there are no 1s or 5s rolled that the print statement "no new points scored, this round ends in a loss" prints out. So if on my first roll I got " 2 3 1 4 5" it would ask if I'd like to roll again, then on the next roll I got " 3 4 1 3 5" it would give me that specific print statement. I guess its important to note also that for each round, once you get a 1 or 5, that specific dice doesn't roll again. I tried to reflect that as best I could in the roll examples I just listed.

Comment: "I guess its important to note also that for each round, once you get a 1 or 5, that specific dice doesn't roll again" - right, that's why it's important that once a 1 or 5 gets rolled, that die gets moved into a different array, so that countFace() will only operate on the dice that were rolled for that round.